# Set table column width depending on order

Tags: css

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I have a table with four `tr` and each `tr` has four `td`.

I want to apply different width's to each td.
For example I want the following:

```
<tr>
   <td width="20%"/>
   <td width="25%"/>
   <td width="10%"/>
   <td width="45%"/>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to have just one class that is applied to the `tr` and inside that class I give a width to each `td`? Or do I create four different classes each with different width's ? Something like

```
.firstTD{
    width:20%; 
} 
.secondTD{
   width:25%; 
} 
.thirdTD{
   width:10%; 
} 
.fourTD{
  width:45%; 
}
```

This should be supported in internet explorer 6 too.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: I don't think you can do this. I believe you will most likely need to use divs and float them to achieve this. I could easily be wrong but that is the approach I would take.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way to do it is as you suggested, creating a CSS class for each TD. In any case, the TD's `class` attribute would be used only for the first row, as the subsequent ones will inherit the `width` value.

Comment: This just happen because i need compatibility with I.E 6,in the above versions i could use adjancent selectors.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adjacent selector:

```
.mytable td{
    width:20%; 
} 
.mytable td+td{
   width:25%; 
} 
.mytable td+td+td{
   width:10%; 
} 
.mytable td+td+td+td{
  width:45%; 
}
```

Like that you wouldn't need any classes, but I would give the table itself one, or all your tables would inherit those styles, obviously.

Comment: It is a good suggestion, and i thank you for this , but the adjacent selector do not work in I.E 6 just above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to use multiple classes. The [adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) has you covered.

```
td { width: 20%; }
td + td { width: 25%; }
td + td + td { width: 10%; }
td + td + td + td { width: 45%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each td to be different widths you'd need to create different classes.  You can set a width on the tr but it will divide up the cells into equal parts or enough to hold the data in them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single class applied to the table (or tbody) and use

```
.yourclass td { /* first td */ }
.yourclass td + td { /* 2nd td */ }
.yourclass td + td + td{ /* 3rd td */ }
.yourclass td + td + td + td { /* 4th td */ }
```

Consider that a rule written in this way will be also applied to all of the following rules, so use this only to set and override specific properties.

If you don't need to supprt older IE version you can also use `nth-child` 
example

```
.yourclass tr td:nth-child(2) { /* 2nd td */ }
```

Note: the class is not strictly necessary but if you have multiple tables, this style will affect only elements you want style in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use define a class in the tr and use :nth-child(n) selector to give each td a separate width

```
<tr class="myrow">
   <td />
   <td />
   <td />
   <td />
</tr>
```

css can be provided as follows,

```
.myrow td:nth-child(1){
    width:20%; 
} 
.myrow td:nth-child(2){
   width:25%; 
} 
.myrow td:nth-child(3){
   width:10%; 
} 
.myrow td:nth-child(4){
  width:45%; 
}
```

But this will work with the browsers that support CSS3. It will be supported from IE9 onwards.